# Codeigniter Template Engine

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

Assume i have controller with the class name "**google**" and it contains some data example

// application/controller/google.php

```
$data = array(
    'target' => 'earth',
    'percentage' => 70
);
```

and its view file is '**google_view.php**' // application/view/google_view.php

and in second controler with the calss name "**msn**" here i want to get the "**google**" controller data .. or i just want to include "**google_view**" file without passing the `$data` variable again

I heard to use of setflash .. but the problem is what if user visit msn page without visiting google

so is there any way to get **google** controller data?

i also checked opencart cms & its an MVC framework in its controller we can call another controller like below.. in below code we can call header controller.

```
$this->children = array(
    'common/column_left',
    'common/column_right',
    'common/content_top',
    'common/content_bottom',
    'common/footer',
    'common/header'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for HMVC features, which CodeIgniter doesn't really do. Take a look at this library which implements it in CI : https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc. There's lots of resources on the net which explain HMVC vs MVC in more detail.

If you're doing this sort of thing on any sort of scale, CodeIgniter might not be the best framework for your application - it would be worth looking at a few others. I'm using a lot of [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) at the minute, which would work perfectly fine if you're just wanting to fetch the output of another controller (eg. in Laravel you just go `$second_controller_output = Route::forward('GET','other/controller');`).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Mmm ... I don't think you do that in CI but I'll suggest one idea ...

Extend the Controller core class, then be sure to extend your new class in your application controller’s constructors. E.g.

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->default_data_google = array(
            'target' => 'earth',
            'percentage' => 70
        );
    }

}

class Google extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $data = $this->default_data_google;
        $this->load->view('google_view', $data);
    }

}

//
```

..

```
class Msn extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $data = $this->default_data_google;
        $this->load->view('google_view', $data);
    }

}
```

Comment: what if data variable is dynamic?

Comment: well - you didn't mention anything about dynamic data in your question - however, you still can fetch data from the database in the MY_conrroller.